# how can i write batch for sql server repetitive tasks

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

i have a table foo in sql server. i need a batch which works every 15 minutes and delete rows,  which is older than 15 minutes, in foo table.

I cannot use trigger. Because triggers are synchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sql server agent job . Add your query to job and schedule it.